# PHP Echo within Stack?

Tags: php, stack, echo

I have the following code:

```
case "links":
        $SideContent ='<a href="http://www.EXAMPLE.net" target="_blank">Example Link</a>';
        break;
```

How do I replace the link area that says "EXAMPLE" with the brand pulled from my list - I've echo'd it on the page but not sure how to use an echo within the existing php code:

```
<?php echo $brand_to_use; ?>
```

IE my aim is as follows:

```
<a href="http://www.$brand_to_use.net"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly,

```
$SideContent ='<a href="'.$brand_to_use.'" target="_blank">'.$brand_to_use.'</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
case "links":
        $SideContent ='<a href="http://www.'.$brand_to_use.'.net" target="_blank">Example Link</a>';
        break;
```